# What is the view's isolation level when you set in stored procedure level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, isolation-level

The title may be hard to read.

Scenario is like this: I have a view `my_view` (by default, it will be read committed). Then I have just created a new stored procedure:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
select *
from table1
inner join my_view
```

Now, of course, table1 will be read uncommitted, but what about `my_view`?

Is it read committed or read uncommitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a view: my_view (read committed)

No, the view does not have an associated isolation level, as you seem to imply.  The view is just a stored query.  And that query will execute in whatever isolation level is in effect at the time you run it.

So if your view is queried from a stored procedure that sets the isolation level to `read uncommitted` (your example), then the query will be executed in that isolation level, simple as that.